# What should I do about a user who wants to delete his account but doesn't know how?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, users, deleted-accounts

Apparently, [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5237180/i-want-to-delete-my-account) and [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2806814/i-want-to-delete-my-account) both want to delete their accounts, but don't know how to do that. I would like to help them out in some way, but I'm not sure how I should help them. Should I comment on one of their posts explaining how they can delete their accounts? Should I flag for moderator attention so that a moderator can help them out? Should I just not do anything? Should I do something else?

In case they manage to delete their accounts, here is a screenshot of one of those users' profile pages:

[image]

Comment: Have you informed the user that deleting their account does not mean their answers and questions are being deleted since that content now belongs to the Stack Exchange community / network?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

Comment: Last seen  6 months ago. I think they gave and don't bother anymore. Possible that they are question/answer banned. Just move on.